# icon fa-twitter : What does this mean?

Tags: css, html, twitter, icons

While looking into a HTML 5 index page source, I got **"icon fa-twitter"**.
On the front end of the Index page, there is the icon of twitter. I tried to search the icon in the files but it is not there.

Could anyone please explain what exactly this means?

Comment: <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>

Comment: this is an icon inserted by css using http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: Font Awesome is indeed awesome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely to be using Font Awesome. Basically an icon font. Please see [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Comment: @SinghGaurav Yep, correct! This method has the benefits of being able to easily update icons, and have them at any size without losing quality :)

Comment: Oh, its a font not image. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is about font awsome :[see doc](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)
Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-twitter">Text</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Font Awesome icons. If you need to use Font Awesome icons please check this link

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

...and take a look at the twitter icon for an example.